# Grails Jasypt plugin Column maxsize always creates varchar instead of text for mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, jasypt

I'm trying to increase the size of the encrypted column

```
static mapping = {
        col1  type: GormEncryptedStringType
}

static constraints = {
        col1(nullable:true)
}
```

It always generates a `varchar(255)` in MySQL while I want it as a text type. I tried adding `maxSize:65000` but then it creates a `varchar(65000)` instead of text.

This field can contain a lot of data and ideally I would want it to be `LONGTEXT` field.

For other non-encypted fields, I successfully used `type:'text'` and it worked but I am stumped since this is an encrypted field and I cant add another type.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type` is the Hibernate Type.  In addition to that trying adding `sqlType` which as the name implies is the underlying SQL column type.

```
static mapping = {
        col1  type: GormEncryptedStringType, sqlType:'TEXT'
}
```

Also, depending on your 'sql type', you can also add `length` to change your column size

```
static mapping = {
        col1  type: GormEncryptedStringType, sqlType:'varchar', length:400
}
```